# Conditional writing of HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am currently trying to create a statement where if it returns false then a label will display on the page with an error message. I have tried using `Response.Write` with no results.

```
if (bannedDomainText.Text.Contains("."))
    File.AppendAllText(MapPath(FILE_PATH), "\r\n" + bannedDomainText.Text);
else
    Response.Write("<label>This isn't working!</label>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Html**

```
<asp:Label ID="ErrorMessage" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

Code

```
if (bannedDomainText.Text.Contains("."))
    File.AppendAllText(MapPath(FILE_PATH), "\r\n" + bannedDomainText.Text);
else
{
    Message.Text =  "This is working";
    Message.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a server side [**label**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) and assign the message to its text property. `You can hide this label or set its text to empty string when you do not want to show the message`.

**In Html**

```
<asp:Label id="lblMessage" runat="server" />
```

**In Code Behind**

```
if (bannedDomainText.Text.Contains("."))
    File.AppendAllText(MapPath(FILE_PATH), "\r\n" + bannedDomainText.Text);
else
    lblMessage.Text =  "This is working";
```

Comment: I have no idea, it wasn't me :P